Why does my interactive problem fail with string queries but works with direct integer inputs?
Problem link = Link
I'm solving an interactive problem, and I'm encountering an issue where my solution works perfectly when I use direct integer inputs/outputs for queries. However, when I attempt to format the query using string concatenation (e.g., "? " + to_string(x) + " " + to_string(y)), the solution fails.
In both cases, I ensure that the output is flushed using flush() after every query. Yet, the first approach doesn't work as expected. Could the string concatenation or output formatting be causing a timing issue or mismatched expectations in the interactive environment? How can I ensure my solution works consistently?
int query(string s) {
    FastIO::println(s);
    FastIO::flush();
    return FastIO::nextInt();
}

void solve() {
    int n = FastIO::nextInt();
    vector<pair<int, int>> list;
    for (int x = 2; x <= n; x++) {
        int y = 1, pre = -1;
        while (pre != y) {
            pre = y;
            y = query("? " + to_string(x) + " " + to_string(y));
        }
        list.push_back({x, pre});
    }

    FastIO::print("! ");
    for (auto &e : list) {
        FastIO::print(to_string(e.first) + " " + to_string(e.second) + " ");
    }
    FastIO::println("");
    FastIO::flush();
}

int main() {
    int t = FastIO::nextInt();
    while (t--) {
        solve();
    }
    return 0;
}


This code did not work  But the next code worked

int query(int x, int y) {
    FastIO::println("? " + to_string(x) + " " + to_string(y));
    FastIO::flush();
    return FastIO::nextInt();
}

void solve() {
    int n = FastIO::nextInt();
    vector<pair<int, int>> list;
    for (int x = 2; x <= n; x++) {
        int y = 1, pre = -1;
        while (pre != y) {
            pre = y;
            y = query(y, x);
        }
        list.push_back({x, pre});
    }

    FastIO::print("! ");
    for (auto &e : list) {
        FastIO::print(to_string(e.first) + " " + to_string(e.second) + " ");
    }
    FastIO::println("");
    FastIO::flush();
}

int main() {
    int t = FastIO::nextInt();
    while (t--) {
        solve();
    }
    return 0;
}


I was expecting both codes to give correct answer.
The java code for both codes was also giving same results.

Side note : "The java code for both codes was also giving same results." This is not the right mindset when starting with C++. Forget evrything you know about Java (or other languages) and how it works, C++ has its own rules and you probably will need to learn them from scratch. Also : No need to use FastIO, just use std::format and std::cout (or std::print C++23)

What does did not work as expected mean? What is the current output and how does it differ from expected output?

The only relevant difference between the two versions is that you've swapped x and y in the second version.
That means that you should get the correct result in the first version too if you did the same swap.
So, instead of:
y = query("? " + to_string(x) + " " + to_string(y));

Make it:
y = query("? " + to_string(y) + " " + to_string(x));


Here's how I reached this conclusion:

Use a tool, like diff, to highlight the differences between two text files. Lines prepended with < comes from version1 and lines prepended with > comes from version2:
$ diff version1.cpp version2.cpp
1,2c1,2
< int query(string s) {
<     FastIO::println(s);
---
> int query(int x, int y) {
>     FastIO::println("? " + to_string(x) + " " + to_string(y));
14c14
<             y = query("? " + to_string(x) + " " + to_string(y));
---
>             y = query(y, x);


We see that in version1, query takes a string and prints it like it is and in version2, query takes two parameters to create the string with the first parameter, x, first and the second parameter, y, second.
In the actual call to query, version1 creates the string using x first and y second while version2 sends in y as the first parameter and x as the second, hence putting y first and x second in the string created inside query.


Oh thanks silly me didnt notice that

@SOUMADIPMISHRA Easy mistake to make. :-)

@SOUMADIPMISHRA You could also take a look at What should I do when someone answers my question? if you haven't already.
